# Terminology for $x=-x$ when x is a positive integer

Tags: proof-writing

My proof by contradiction ends with $x=-x$ when x is a positive integer. What is the correct terminology for *why* this is a contradiction?

Right now it says "This yields a contradiction since a positive integer cannot equal the negative value of itself", but I'm sure there's a theorum or something for this.

Thank you!

Comment: You should probably give some context as to what the proof is, and what you tried.

Comment: What does the $/$ mean?

Comment: Did you mean $x\ne -x$? If you did then that isn't necessarily a contradiction unless $x=0$.

Comment: @LaarsHelenius: You mean "unless $x\ne 0$", right?

Comment: In some cases, $x = -x$ and not just for 0.  In a field of characteristic 2 for example.

Comment: @MarkPineau I added what I have now

Comment: @kingW3 It means I can't type ;0

Comment: @LaarsHelenius It's $x=-x$ when $x$ is a positive integer.

Comment: @badjohn: But the integers are clearly not a field of characteristic $2$. Indeed, in a field of characteristic $2$ (or of any positive characteristic) you cannot define an order, and therefore the term "positive" does not make sense. Indeed, wherever "positive" makes sense, the sum of two positive elements is again a positive element, which excludes $x+x=0$ for any positive $x$, as $0$ by definition is not positive.

Comment: If $x$ is a positive integer then $-x<x$ and because you obtained $-x=x$, we get a contradiction according to Trichotomy Law.

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan So how would I write that in the "yields a contradiction because..." form?

Comment: @celtschk Yes but at the time of my post, there was less information in the question.  I don't think that it mentioned "positive integer" at that point.  If it did then I apologise for having read it too quickly.

Comment: You already said that you end up with $-x=x$ where $x$ is a positive integer, right? This is not possible because $-x<x$. See and google Trichotomy Law

Comment: @badjohn I added it after your comment, you're good :)

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Gotcha. If you want to post as an answer I'll accept it -- thanks!

Comment: @GiantDuck Thanks.  I am an old man now and my knowledge is quite rusty.  I am here to try to polish it up.  It's good to know that I am not going senile and just missing half of your question.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Of course! I need to read what I type before I hit send more often!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Trichotomy Law:** If $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ then exactly one of the following holds
>   $$(i)a>b\quad (ii)a=b\quad (iii)a<b$$

In your case, we have $-x<x$ since $x$ is positive integer. Thus, by the above law, $-x\neq x$. This is in contradiction to the one you obtained $-x=x$.

Answer (score 2):

You can do another proof by contradiction for that:

Assume $x\ne0$ and $x=-x$. Since $x$ is not $0$, we may divide by $x$ to achieve: $1=-1$. This is a falsity. Therefore we conclude $x=0$, which is not a positive number.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that $x=-x$ is equivalent to $x+x = 0$, equivalent to $x = 0$.